# Why do I get an error when I try to insert data into my table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I've a homework from school to do and a big problem with inserting the data into my table. The sql-file has this query:

```
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('06.07.13','LH-888','Boeing','B747','9fg-he-ztu8',10010071,11.23);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('08.10.13','LH-238','Airbus','A320','z3et-bwe7',10010072,22.06);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('13.11.13','LH-341','Boeing','B737','ba23-0012',10010001,10.23);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('14.11.13','LH-358','Boeing','B737','ba23-0012',10010001,08.17);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('13.11.13','LH-553','Boeing','B777','xv23-0889',10010002,16.53);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('15.11.13','LH-421','Boeing','B777','xv56-3142',10010002,14.45);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('17.11.13','LH-789','Airbus','A330','45-6789',10010003,8.11);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('14.11.13','LH-112','Boeing','B737','ba23-0034',10010001,8.14);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('17.11.13','LH-421','Boeing','B777','xv23-0889',10010002,16.26);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('18.11.13','LH-223','Airbus','A380','ab-45-6xf',10010004,09.45);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('19.11.13','LH-634','Airbus','A350','5478-awe3',10010005,20.25);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,SER_NR,PER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('18.02.14','LH-238','Airbus','A320','z3et-bwe7',10010072,23.06);
```

Everytime I want to run it in the SQL Workshop on my Oracle Application Express 11g I am getting this error:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Is there an error in the syntax? Am I forgetting some parentheses? Or something else?
This is the infos about the table, in which I want to insert the data into:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFkxZ.png)

I would be very thankful for your help. I am just starting to learn SQL at my class. Thank you!

Comment: Try inserting one row at a time. Do you get the error for each line, or just for one?

Comment: when I insert just one line, I am getting this message: 

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ORACLEKURS.FK_ABFLUG_MIT_FLUGZEUG) violated - parent key not found

Comment: Are you trying to run multiple statements at once in the 'SQL Command' area; or using 'SQL Scripts'?

Comment: Well, it worked after I've dropped the old table and rearranged it like this:
create table abflug (
 ab_datum varchar2(15),
 f_bez varchar2(10),
 herst varchar2(10),
 typ varchar2(10),
 per_nr varchar2(15),
 ser_nr integer,
 ab_zeit number(9,2)
);

But only when I've inserted them line by line.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apex SQL Worksheet, but it only accepts one command at a time. Maybe if you convert it into a single PL/SQL block by putting `begin` at the top and `end;` at the bottom, it will accept that.

Comment: Does your assignment include the table definition? It seems like `ab_datum` should be `date`, not `varchar2(15)`. If it's a date column, you write dates like this: `date '2013-07-07'` (but don't try to put dates in a varchar2 column or strings in a date column).

Answer (score 1):

Your column list for the INSERTs is incorrect. This works -

```
--drop table abflug purge;

create table abflug (
 ab_datum varchar2(15),
 f_bez varchar2(10),
 herst varchar2(10),
 typ varchar2(10),
 per_nr varchar2(15),
 ser_nr integer,
 ab_zeit number(9,2)
);



insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('06.07.13','LH-888','Boeing','B747','9fg-he-ztu8',10010071,11.23);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('08.10.13','LH-238','Airbus','A320','z3et-bwe7',10010072,22.06);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('13.11.13','LH-341','Boeing','B737','ba23-0012',10010001,10.23);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('14.11.13','LH-358','Boeing','B737','ba23-0012',10010001,08.17);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('13.11.13','LH-553','Boeing','B777','xv23-0889',10010002,16.53);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('15.11.13','LH-421','Boeing','B777','xv56-3142',10010002,14.45);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('17.11.13','LH-789','Airbus','A330','45-6789',10010003,8.11);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('14.11.13','LH-112','Boeing','B737','ba23-0034',10010001,8.14);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('17.11.13','LH-421','Boeing','B777','xv23-0889',10010002,16.26);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('18.11.13','LH-223','Airbus','A380','ab-45-6xf',10010004,09.45);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('19.11.13','LH-634','Airbus','A350','5478-awe3',10010005,20.25);
insert into abflug (AB_DATUM,F_BEZ,HERST,TYP,PER_NR,SER_NR,AB_ZEIT) values
('18.02.14','LH-238','Airbus','A320','z3et-bwe7',10010072,23.06);
```

You're trying to send strings to number columns.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and time! I've copied your query to create the new table and after trying to insert the data (copy&paste what you've put here), I am getting the same error message: 
ORA-00911: invalid character

It seems that there is some syntax error in it? I have tried with only one line and it worked... The row was inserted.

Comment: APEX SQL Worksheet - you have to execute each statement, one at a time. Or upload a script and execute that.